# How can I inject a String value defined in a xml file into a component class member?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, annotations

For instance, in the xml file, I have defined some String values:

```
<bean id="name" class="java.lang.String" >
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="SMITH" />
</bean>
```

While in the component class, how can I inject this into its class member?

```
@Component
public class Person {
    private String name; // @Autowired doesn't work here
}
```

How can I inject the String 'name' defined in the xml file into Person? @Autowired doesn't work. Is there any workaround here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to annotate with `@Resource`

```
@Resource(name="name") 
private String name;
```